# Optimization for inequalities in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: equation-solving, complex

I want to check when the expression

$$
\sqrt{\sqrt{\lambda^{2}\left(2E+\lambda^{2}\right)}+E+\lambda^{2}}
$$

is real, when it is purely imaginary and when it is complex (with imaginary part not zero).

Also I would like to know  the sign of the imaginary part in the case it is non-zero. To check the last part, after some steps, I am using `Reduce` for inequalities like $\mathrm{Im}\left(\sqrt{\lambda^{2}\left(2E+\lambda^{2}\right)}\right)>0 $ but this is taking a lot of time on *Mathematica*. Is there a way to get the kind of results that I want more quickly?

The variables are real and the code I ran is

```
  Reduce[ Im[ Sqrt[ e + λ^2  -Sqrt[ λ^2 (2 e + λ^2)]]] > 0, {e, λ}]
```

Comment: Can you include the code which is taking a long time?

Comment: Are the variables real ?

Comment: `Reduce[Im[Sqrt[e + x^2 + Sqrt[(x^2) (2*e + x^2)]]] == 0, x, Reals]` for real vars

Comment: @belisarius Interestingly, Reduce doesn't seem to solve the <0 case correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Let's see what are the regions of interest:

```
n = 4;
Partition[
   RegionPlot[#[[2]][#[[1]][Sqrt[e + x^2 + Sqrt[(x^2) (2*e + x^2)]]], 0], 
             {x, -n, n}, {e, -n, n}, PlotLabel -> #, 
             AxesLabel -> Automatic, LabelStyle -> Medium] & /@ 
                                                 Tuples@{{Re, Im}, {Less, Greater}},
   2] // Grid // Framed
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So in principle we should only focus on the sign of the imaginary part. Like this:

```
Reduce[Im[Sqrt[e + x^2 + Sqrt[(x^2) (2*e + x^2)]]] == 0, e, Reals]
(*
 e >= -(x^2/2)
*)
```

and that's the information you were after.